# NVD3.js: ReferenceError: nv is not defined

Tags: nvd3.js

I am using NVD3.js library to generate graph. I tried adding line chart into it & getting the above error. How to resolve it?

I am trying this [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post a Plunker/Fiddle? Off the top of my head, it may just be where you're including the nv.d3.js. Did you also include D3.js?

Comment: yes. i think i need to add D3.V3.min.js also. i havent seen the home page of NVD3.js website directly went to graph examples where there is no reference for files to be included.....thanks

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: You need to make sure D3 is included before using NVD3.
http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

Answer (score 4):

Actually i found out, the problem was the folder structure. The examples that comes with the angular-nvd3 website gives path

> bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js

, check in  your bower_components file the actual path would be

> bower_components/nvd3/**build**/nv.d3.js

Similarly the nv.d3.css path is NOT

> bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.css

it is,

> bower_components/nvd3/**build**/nv.d3.css

Also, DON'T forget to add

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

as the first line inside your head tag..

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem working with ionic2 (based on Angular2).

> Although all the necessary libraries were included in the index.html. 
>   The problem finaly was that the scripts has to be included before the
>   ionic app is loaded!!!

```
<!-- These scripts are copied from node_modules-->
  <script src="build/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="build/nv.d3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did u include `nv.d3.js` & `d3.js` as the sequence of these will also cause issues Try adding `d3.js` first

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Add these files in your index.html**

> 

Comment: Also need to add dependencies in package.json if you have forgotten

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 2 or higher version, then

```
"../node_modules/ng2-nvd3/node_modules/d3/d3.min.js",
"../node_modules/ng2-nvd3/node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.js"
```

Just add above lines under `scripts` array in `.angular-cli.json`.

Comment: Thanks for giving a easy understanding solution